# Figuring percentage when mean and standard deviation are given

Tags: descriptive-statistics

Consider the mean combined SAT score for high school seniors is 1500, and the standard deviation is 250. Calculate the percentage of students who scored at the following levels:

```
Below 1000.
Above 1750.
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your thoughts and efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts. 
You are more likely to receive positive/constructive feedback that way.  
Formatting your post helps too.
Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).